# Error in creating simulator build for facebook submission for review zip

Tags: ios, xcode7, ditto

When I try to create simulator build, it will show this error:

```
Admins-Mac-mini:~ admin$ ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/bam.zip

**ditto: Can't archive multiple sources**

**Usage: ditto [ <options> ] src [ ... src ] dst**

Admins-Mac-mini:~ admin$
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

if you directory name has space(s) then command will not work. don't forget to add escape character before space. I have note-down whole command which has destination directory name(untitled folder) with space character.

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` /Users/imediaimac/Desktop/untitled\ folder/test.zip
```

given command works properly without any problem.

**Solution 2:**

- **Step 1**: open finder and press command⌘ + shift⇧ + g
- **Step 2**: paste "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"
- **Step 3**: select your_app_name-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh some thing like this folder
- **Step 4**: your_app_name-jkfksdfhskdhfksdh >>Build >>Products>>Debug-iphoneos
- **Step 5**: You will see 2 files one is your_app_name.app(icon like rounder and 1 cross line ) and 2nd file is your_app_name.app.dSYM
- **Step 6**: To create .zip file right click on your_app_name.app and select "Compress your_app_name". It will generate .zip file and submit it to facebook.

For more details visit Facebook [official documentation here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced)

Comment: Thumbs up for solution 2.

Answer (score 0):

This has solved same issue. Remove whitespace/space from .app name

ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t /Users/company/Desktop/Build/appname.app | head -n 1` /Users/company/Desktop/Build/appname.zip